# Azure DevOps creates links to forked repository when commit mentioning is disabled

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I have the following workflow in Azure DevOps:

1. Create a new fork of the repository
2. Create a new branch in the fork from the master branch
3. Set the new branch as the default branch in the fork
4. Set policies on the new branch in the fork

The problem I'm having is that ADO is automatically adding links in workitems to commits in the forked repository. *Commit mention linking* and *Commit mention work item resolution* options are disabled by default in forks, and I even disabled these options in the original repository, but ADO is still adding these links.

Did I miss something obvious here or is it a bug in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? We're having the same problem.

Comment: Not really, but it stopped happening at some point for reason unknown to me. I created issue in developer community (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-DevOps-creates-links-in-workitems/10173807) but as a workaround they suggested to create copy of the repo instead of forking it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update.
I guess that's what we're gonna do now, too. Thanks for providing the link to your ticket!